# Online platform for learning Greek

Tags: resource-request, online-learning, greek

I'm searching for an online platform for learning the Greek language. It's important for me to learn spelling and writing with both the old and new Greek alphabets.

Is there a platform for this? And if yes, it would be nice to know if they are available for free or paid access only.

It would be great to have some kind of voice recognition which let me know if I spell everything right or not.

The interface and all feedback can be in English or German. Both would fit.

Comment: I have edited your question slightly simply to ask for Greek online resources. Asking for "good" things is quite subjective.  It would also be helpful if you tell us what searching you have done, and why it has come up short for you.

Comment: I wonder if you could explain what you mean by "platform". Some responses are recommending apps, which I would not consider a "platform".

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe well even an app is something like a platform. Not in the same way as an developer would define it. Just call it some kind of online place where I'm able to learn a specific language alone or together with other individuals.

Comment: @Ionic That's an important clarification. Could you please edit your question to add this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick search reveals that there are several online Greek learning courses.

[Rosetta Stone](http://www.rosettastone.com/lp/ppc/sale/?cid=se-br-gg-grill&gclid=Cj0KEQjwte27BRCM6vjIidHvnKQBEiQAC4MzrY3MXrNsqzcTTmDgUl3Jd4Bg0zXOw_udlqj_vetwUTMaAlOL8P8HAQ) has a Greek course that you can purchase for $189 USD in CD-ROM format, online, or as a desktop download.

If you'd prefer more personal lessons, you can take Skype lessons with a Greek tutor. [Eleni Pateraki](http://www.verbalplanet.com/publicviewprofile.asp?tr_id=10009796681&lang=GRE&lang2=GRE#tab_feedback), according to over 450 reviews, has an average rating of 100%, with past students complimenting her enthusiasm as helpful teaching techniques. She charges €25.76 for a 45 minute lesson.

A free online Greek resource is [Learn Greek Online!](http://www.kypros.org/LearnGreek/), which "is currently composed of 105 real audio files (around 15 minutes each), online student notes, a collection of collaborative learning tools and an online greek dictionary and a greek spell checker", according to the website.

Duolingo also has a [free Greek course](https://www.duolingo.com/course/el/en/Learn-Greek-Online) that launched in September 2016.

Comment: Just got their Mail. :-)

Answer (score 4):

[Clozemaster](https://www.clozemaster.com/languages/learn-greek-from-english) might be useful for learning Greek once you have the basics down with something like Duolingo or Memrise (both free resources suitable for beginners). The goal is to learn vocab in context by answering the missing word for thousands of sentences. There's a text input mode so you can practice correct spelling, and you can play with translations in English or [German](https://www.clozemaster.com/languages/learn-greek-from-german). There are some advanced paid features, but it's otherwise free to sign up and play.

Answer (score 1):

Memrise also has some Greek courses:

https://www.memrise.com/courses/english/greek/

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the best platforms out there is [staellinika.com](https://www.staellinika.com)

"StaEllinika is an initiative of the General Secretariat for Greeks Abroad and Public Diplomacy at the Ministry of Foreign Affairs in collaboration with the Ministry of Education and Religious Affairs and the SNF Centre For Hellenic Studies at Simon Fraser University (SFU) with support by the Stavros Niarchos Foundation (SNF). Starting in the fall of 2020, Staellinika will offer a full curriculum targeting beginner heritage learners in schools and individuals at home."

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on google and I found a free app for beginners called, ironically, Beginner Greek (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shex.beginnergreek). It seems to be a vocabulary tool meant for beginners in learning the common Greek words.

Answer (score 0):

Learning different languages is a good practice. If you want to learn the Greek language then I suggest Native Monks website and the link is here: https://nativemonks.com/greek-classes. You will definitely get good help from this website. You can select a tutor according to your requirements. I am pretty sure that you will be able to speak, write and read this language. You will get these services at very affordable prices. I learned Japanese, German languages from this website. I am very happy to take their services. The tutors are also good. You can select your classes’ timings according to your comfort so that it will not affect your work. If you are learning from online websites then you should be very careful while selecting any course.

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange and thank you for your contribution. Does the Native Monks website only help you find tandem partners or tutors or does it also provide courses and/or other learning materials for Greek? If it does not provide learning resources, I'm not sure if it is the type of site that @ionic is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Mango Languages offers courses in Modern, Ancient, and Koine Greek.](https://mangolanguages.com/available-languages/) Depending on where you live, [you may be able to get access to their language courses for free](https://mangolanguages.com/find-mango/), usually through your local library.

This webpage claims to allow you to download the [Foreign Service Institute's 1967 Greek curriculum,](https://www.fsi-language-courses.org/fsi-greek-basic-course/) (for free, but with the caveat that you need to give them your email address).

[This website also offers the FSI Greek curriculum,](https://www.livelingua.com/project/fsi/greek) and is hosted by LiveLingua.

And then, of course, there's [Duo](https://www.duolingo.com/course/el/en/Learn-Greek)[lingo](https://de.duolingo.com/course/el/en/Lerne-Griechisch).